# iOS Simulator - Dragging images from Finder Not Adding to Photos in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode10

Just installed macOS Mojave and Xcode 10. I'm trying to drag images from Finder onto the Simulator to add them to Photos, which was working the day before on High Sierra and Xcode 9.

Does anyone know if Apple has changed / blocked this or if there is another solution to get local images into Photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hold the image to Photos icon and drop it, this will help you.

-Drag a photo

[image]

Result:-
[image]

Comment: I can only add 1 photo add a time - used to be able to drag a group of photos in - thanks that worked though!

Comment: Just tested it and it does not make a difference whether you drop the image on the Photos icon or not. Refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52518756/3151675) for details.

Answer (score 4):

As of `Version 10.1 (SimulatorApp-877 CoreSimulator-581.2)`, I found what works for now.
For some reason keeping the Finder window in the background and keeping the simulator window in the foreground while dragging and dropping the photo into Photos app works.  Selecting multiple photos does not work since trying to do that brings the Finder into foreground.

[image]

Make sure your *Finder* stays in the background and, no, selecting multiple images does not seem to work no matter what I have tried.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you have to **hold the image you're dragging** over the Simulator window **for a few seconds** (specifically, until the window gets into focus and the little plus symbol next to the cursor disappears). This might be a bug in Xcode 10.

Comment: This only works _sometimes_.  See below for one that works 100% of the time.

Answer (score -2):

The drag&drop feature works well in XCode 12. If it isn't working for you, just try to quit and reopen the simulator.